# Converting Leads in Apex - defaulting to account owner

Tags: apex, lead-conversion

I've been converting leads into a matched account and never had an issue. I wanted to add logic that would route the contact to a specific user.

In this case id = '005E0000009eQ3A' *I get that that's not set to scale*

The issue I'm facing is that when the lead is converted, the owner is defaulting to the account owner rather than the id I passed.

Am I using `setOwnerId(UserId)` incorrectly? Is there something I missed?

```
leadConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
convertStatus = new LeadStatus();

convertStatus = [SELECT MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted = true limit 1];

Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(theLead.Id);
lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
lc.setAccountId(theLead.Matched_Account__c);
lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
lc.setOwnerId('005E0000009eQ3A');

if (!leadConverts.isEmpty()) {
    List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(leadConverts);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_convertLead.htm) :

> **setOwnerId** Specifies the ID of the person to own any newly created account, contact, and opportunity. If the application does not specify
>   this value, the owner of the new object will be the owner of the lead.
>   **This method is not applicable when merging with existing objects—if
>   setOwnerId is specified, the ownerId field is not overwritten in an
>   existing account or contact**.

So, when you are merging with existing Account, this wont work.
Also your code example doesnt add the variable **lc** to **leadConverts** list and is using hard coded user Id which is a bad practice.

Comment: my apologies for failing to include `leadConverts.add(lc);` that is present in my existing code.

That said, I'm not merging existing objects, i'm converting a lead into new contact.

Is it not possible to `SetOwnerId` if the account already exists but the contact does not?

Comment: Yes, the ownerid field is not overwritten in an existing account even if the Contact doesnt exist.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that it currently IS being overwritten

Comment: It is overwritten to the owner id you specified in setOwnerId method or something else ?

Comment: The Contact with inherit the Account Owner as you are specifying the AccountId while converting the lead. The workaround would be to explicitly query the ConvertedContactId in after update trigger event on Lead conversion and update the Contact with the Owner.

Comment: It is being set to the Account Owner's Id. What's the point of `SetOwnerId` method if it's just going to be overwritten?

Comment: It is applicable only for create of Account, Contact and Opportunity all together.

Answer (score 1):

> You didn't add `lc` into `leadConverts` list.

That's why it is assigning the default account ownerId.

> Secondly, it is a bad practice to hardcode Salesforce Id in code.

You should retrieve that specific user and use that userId.

```
leadConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
convertStatus = new LeadStatus();

convertStatus = [SELECT MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted = true limit 1];

Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(theLead.Id);
lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
lc.setAccountId(theLead.Matched_Account__c);
lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
lc.setOwnerId(userId); //do not hard code user Id
leadConverts.add(lc); //add this line

if (!leadConverts.isEmpty()) {
    List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(leadConverts);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I do have `leadConverts.add(lc);` present in my existing code but made a mistake when copy/pasting. That said, even with SetOwnerId set correctly(as you recommended) the newly created contact is being assigned to the current account owner, not the `UserId` passed into `setOwnerId()

Comment: what is the OWD of contact, is that Controlled By Parent or private?

Comment: OWD for Contact is Controlled by parent - OWD for Account is Public read/write